# Can I use one sample t-test to test whether the relative difference is statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, gaussian-process

So I am running an A/B test to check if my new pricing policy results in at least 5% increase in total revenue. So I have two columns of raw data

1st column: ***weekly_revenue_control_group*** which consists of weekly cumulative revenues generated by the sales of all control group items in each week (over the testing period).

2nd column ***weekly_revenue_test_group*** which consists of weekly cumulative revenues generated by the sales of all test group items in each week (over the testing period).

I created a 3rd column called ***percentage changes*** with the formula:
$percentage\_change_{i}\ = \frac{weekly\_revenue\_test\_group_{i}\ - \ weekly\_revenue\_control\_group_{i}}{weekly\_revenue\_control\_group_{i}}$

I want to perform a hypothesis testing using only the 3rd column which has less than 30 observations and have a gaussian distribution as can be seen
below[image]

```
Null hypothesis: mean of percentage changes = 5 
Alternative hypothesis: mean of percentage changes < 5
```

Since I don’t know the true population variance and sample size of ***percentage changes*** is below 30, I want to test this hypothesis with one sample t-test.

My first question: can I do that because after all I created the 3rd column called ***percentage changes*** and it doesn’t have to be continuous (if ${weekly\_revenue\_control\_group_{i}=0}$ for any week then it is not ) so it violates one of the assumptions of t-test?

And my second question: if I can use t-test, how am I supposed to calculate the standart deviation and mean of my 3rd column, namely my test statistics?

Thank you!

Comment: Why one-sample? Don’t you have multiple samples?

Comment: Yes I have two samples but I dont want to test an hypothesis if the means of weekly_revenue_control_group and weekly_revenue_test_group are equal or not. I want test a hypothesis that claims the mean percentage change in revenue is smaller than 5.

Comment: Where does the 30 come from? How many items are in each group?

Comment: Have you considered applying the delta method to the percent change?

Comment: 30 is the sample size of ***percentage change*** of which each item is calculated with the above formulation by using two of my observed samples ***weekly_revenue_control_group*** and ***weekly_revenue_test_group***. Delta method is for calculating the standard deviation of the sample ***percentage change***, right?